# How to pull out a variable from mysql then pull out another variable from that former variable?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm currently trying to find out how I can output a value that can be found in my database table, basically it has 4 columns, id, last_claim, last_login and last_activity

I've tried this

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `last_claim` FROM `faucet_user_list` WHERE id = '".$user['id']."'");

var_dump($result);
```

to pull out the value of last_claim from the current user's ID variable. But to no avail. Do you know what I should do to actually pull the value out?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is inside `$user['id']` and how to you assign it? What does _But to no avail_ means here? What do you get as the result of `var_dump($result);` line?

Answer (score 0):

The `$result` returned by `$mysqli->query` isn't the array itself, but rather an object of the mysqli_result type ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)).

You need to create the actual array to access the data. First, I would check to ensure that results were returned with the [`num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) method.

```
if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {

}
```

Then, once you have established that you have rows in your result, you can query the first row, since based on my understanding of the question, that's all you need. You can use either [`fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php), [`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), or [`fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php), depending which format and number of records you want.

Putting it all together, you get:

```
if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); // Get an associative array for the first row
    echo $row['last_claim'].'<br />'; // The array keys are the field names in the SQL query
}
```

Perhaps out of scope for this question, but your query is vulnerable to SQL injection and should utlize the parameterized query binding that is supported in MySQLi.